# Тире или скобки при уточнении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложении: "Рельеф низкий, ниже халькопирита и сфалерита – II группа", II группа обособляется в скобках или перед ней ставится тире?

Comment: Эх-эх! Контекста бы...

Comment: Диски спесьляются... Нужен профильный специалист.

Comment: Сфалерит образует идиоморфные кристаллы кубического облика (рисунок 5) и зернистые ксеноморфные агрегаты размером от 0,1 до 5 мм. Цвет светло-серый. Отражательная способность низкая – 16%. Двуотражения нет. Изотропен при скрещенных николях. Внутренние рефлексы слабые желтовато-коричневые. Рельеф выше галенита, ниже пирита – III группа. III группа обособляется в скобках или перед ней ставится тире.

Answer (score 2):

1. Чтобы дать правильный ответ, нужно знать не только правила пунктуации, но и **тематику вопроса**, то есть понимать смысл сказанного.
2. Информация **для справок** (можно не читать, это для тех, кому интересно)

Здесь речь идет о систематике минералов по относительному рельефу, а фактически говорится о твердости минералов, то есть для неизвестного минерала нужно определить группу твердости. https://irbis.amursu.ru/DigitalLibrary/AmurSU_Edition/5868.pdf  Таблица 5, стр. 24.

По таблице видно, что у  группы I самый низкий рельеф/твердость, халькопирит – это III группа,  сфалерит –  IV группа. И тогда определяемый минерал располагается между группой I и группой III/IV, то есть это группа II.

3. **Ответ**

Итак,  **II группа** – это определение (в лабораторных условиях) группы, к которой принадлежит минерал.

(1) Подробно вывод можно записать так:  Рельеф низкий, ниже халькопирита (III группа) и сфалерита (IV группа), то есть это II группа.

Или:  Рельеф низкий (ниже халькопирита и сфалерита) – это II группа.

(2) Но специалисты используют **краткие записи с тире**: Рельеф низкий, ниже халькопирита и сфалерита – II группа.

Также: Отражательная способность низкая – 16%. Рельеф выше галенита, ниже пирита – III группа.

Answer (score 1):

***Рельеф низкий, ниже халькопирита и сфалерита (II группа).***

Конечно, в вашем примере выделение вставной конструкции (II группа) возможно **только скобками**: если отделить вставную конструкцию, стоящую в конце предложения, тире, то она потеряет свою выставочность и может быть воспринята как любой другой обособленный оборот или часть сложного предложения.

Справочник Лопатина:

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128

> Выделение [вставных конструкций] с помощью парного тире возможно только в середине предложения, так как в конце предложения отделенная знаком тире вставная конструкция при соответствующей структуре будет воспринята как вторая часть сложного предложения. Чтобы вставка сохранила свой «вставочный» характер, здесь необходимы скобки.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста! Если вас полностью устраивает мой ответ, вы можете поставить ему плюсик и принять его.

Comment: Сфалерит образует идиоморфные кристаллы кубического облика (рисунок 5) и зернистые ксеноморфные агрегаты размером от 0,1 до 5 мм. Цвет светло-серый. Отражательная способность низкая – 16%. Двуотражения нет. Изотропен при скрещенных николях. Внутренние рефлексы слабые желтовато-коричневые. Рельеф выше галенита, ниже пирита – III группа. III группа обособляется в скобках или перед ней ставится тире. В словосочетании% Отражательная способность низкая - 16%. 16% выделяется в скобках, перед ним ставится тире или можно вообще никаких знаков не ставить